# Capturing multiline region defined by start and end patterns

Tags: awk

I want to print an intervening section (between a start pattern and an end pattern) from a file, with particular lines getting coloured.

Here is a sample text in one such file

```
## Beginning of file

Some text and code

## FAML [ASMB] KEYWORD
##  Some information.
##  Some other text.
##  Blu:
##  Some text in blue.
## END OF FAML [ASMB]

## Other text

More text and code
```

The text between `## FAML [ASMB] KEYWORD` and `## END OF FAML [ASMB]` is to be extracted (without the beginning `##`) and passed to the function `luciferin` which will print the multiline text appropriately.

The text between blocks is discarded. Subsequent blocks work the same, the intervening region is extracted and printed by calling the function `luciferin(rec)`. The function `luciferin` does the output in colour.

The input string for `luciferin` would be

```
Some information.
Some other text.
Blu:
Some text in blue.
```

Here is the awk script that captures the intervening region

```
BEGIN {
  beg_ere = "## [[:alnum:]]+ [[][[:alnum:]]+[]]"
  end_ere = "## END OF [[:alnum:]]+ [[][[:alnum:]]+[]]"
 }

match($0, beg_ere, paggr) { display = 1 }
$0 ~ end_ere { display = 0 ; next }
display { print }
```

Here is the `luciferin` function that takes a string for output in colour.  Where `cpt` in the colour escape sequence, and `astr[i]` is a particular line `i` of the multiline input string.

```
function luciferin(mstr) {
  cpt = tseq["Grn:"]
  nlines = split(mstr, astr, "\n")
  for (i = 1; i <= nlines; i++) {
    for ( knam in tseq ) {
      if ( knam == astr[i] ) { cpt = tseq[knam] ; break }
     }
    if (knam == str) { print "" } else { print cpt astr[i] rst }
   }

 }
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. How to do it depends on what you want to do, and the best way to show that is by including an example in your question.  Showing both example input and the expected output given that input ensures that we can test our solutions for correctness.

Comment: Did you try yourself with some `sed '/start-pattern/,/end-pattern/!d'` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's neither a minimal complete example of code, nor adequate sample input/output to test with, this is obviously just an untested guess but it looks like you should change:

```
display { print }
```

to

```
display { rec = rec $0 ORS }
```

and

```
$0 ~ end_ere { display = 0 ; next }
```

to

```
$0 ~ end_ere { luciferin(rec); rec = ""; display = 0 ; next }
```

or similar and tweak `luciferin` to remove the additional trailing newline from it's arg before printing.

---

Regarding how the question and the OPs questions in general could be improved - here's what a complete, minimal code sample would look like in a question such as this one:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$2 == "FAML" { display = 1 ; next }
$2 == "END" { display = 0 ; next }
display { print }

function luciferin(mstr) {
    nlines = split(mstr, astr, "\n")
    for (i = 1; i <= nlines; i++) {
        print "Luci:", astr[i]
    }
}
```

and some sample input to demonstrate your needs and test with:

```
$ cat input
## Beginning of file

Some text and code

## FAML [ASMB] KEYWORD
##  Some information.
##  Some other text.
## END OF FAML [ASMB]

## Other text

## FAML [ASMB] KEYWORD
##  Some other information.
##  Even more text.
## END OF FAML [ASMB]

More text and code
```

and the expected output given that input:

```
Luci: ##  Some information.
Luci: ##  Some other text.
Luci: ##  Some other information.
Luci: ##  Even more text.
```

The fact that your real code does coloring or whatever else is utterly irrelevant to the problem you want help with which is simply how to store a block of text and call `luciferin()` to print it modified in some way.

Given a clear, simple example like that we can very quickly show you a solution, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$2 == "FAML" { display = 1 ; next }
$2 == "END" { luciferin(rec); rec = ""; display = 0 ; next }
display { rec = rec $0 ORS }

function luciferin(mstr) {
    nlines = split(mstr, astr, "\n")
    for (i = 1; i < nlines; i++) {
        print "Luci:", astr[i]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input
Luci: ##  Some information.
Luci: ##  Some other text.
Luci: ##  Some other information.
Luci: ##  Even more text.
```

which you can then take away and apply the concepts from it to your real code.

Comment: How is the sample input/output to test with insufficient?

Comment: The fact your code continues after the end_ere matches tells me your real input contains multiple blocks to extract but your sample input only has 1 block so we can't test what happens to the text between blocks, or what should separate output blocks, if anything, and you don't show the expected output at all, just the string you want to run your function on which isn't the same as the desired output from your script. Plus even if it was there Id have to piece together the script fragments and add other code around it before I could test it.

Comment: Please look at the minimal, complete code, sample input, and expected output that clearly and simply demonstrate all the requirements associated with the problem you're asking for help to solve. THAT is the kind of example you should provide in every question - minimal, complete, and testable.

Answer (score 1):

Tackling this in `awk` is certainly feasible, but
it seems you're making this much too hard on yourself.
`Perl` offers language support for such ranges directly,
copied from the `sed` feature that was mentioned in the comments.

Let's color spring months blue.

```
$ cat months.txt | perl -ane 'print "blue" if /Mar/../May/; print "\t$_"'
        January
        February
blue    March
blue    April
blue    May
        June
```

Use FAML / ASMB keywords in those regexes to adapt this to your use case.

---

Even if you wish to do fancier processing than this,
it is still a good initial stage in your pipeline.

Now a subsequent stage doesn't have to worry about line ranges;
it can use first field to identify whether we're within range or not
and then process the rest of the line accordingly.

Comment: Ahhhmmm: Why use `cat` vs `perl -ane '...' months.txt`?

Comment: @drewk, for [pedagogical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedagogy) purposes. I was hoping to draw a neophyte into the practice of composing and iterating on pipelines, letting the 2nd stage focus on the transformation rather than the data source.